# Asian time travel movie about kids who go into a cave and stop ageing

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

Last year, I saw an Asian movie on Tubi about three kids who go into a cave (actually, a large hole in the ground). When an earthquake-like event happens, one of the boys stays behind after the other two leave the cave. This boy stops ageing. The final shot at the end of the film shows the boy on a ship talking to a young girl. It's a wonderful story, but I can't remember the name of it.

Please note, this is not the 2017 film "Time Trap."

Answer (score 6):

Is it [Vanishing Time: A boy who returned](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_Time:_A_Boy_Who_Returned)? Although I don't recall the earthquake event, the rest of the story seems to fit:

> A 13-year-old boy named Sung-min and his two friends went missing after their venture into a cave in a forest, along with a girl, Su-rin. Later, a mysterious man in his 30s shows up and tells Su-rin that he is her friend Sung-min

Comment: Yes! Thank you! "Vanishing Time" is indeed the name of the movie. So glad I joined this forum! Craig

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it clicking the checkmark beside my answer and upvoting by clicking the up button! :3 If you plan to ask more questions here, then you read the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour/) too!